# jQuery : Test if element is visible on screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

---

**Note** : this is *not* a question about `display:none;`.

---

I have different elements in various containers, which are set `overflow:auto;`. I want to test if any given element is visible in the browser.

Precisions :

- I assume (read "I don't care if") there is no absolute element floating on top
- The container may be absolute
- The element may be part visible

This function will be called on `window` (or any scrollable) scroll events to check if an element disappear or reappear in the viewport, and the observed element may be inside a scrollable DIV.

Is this too much work to generalize such validation?

Comment: Would this jQuery plugin by of any use to you by any chance? - http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

Answer (score 1):

This will return true if an element is visible within the specified container:

```
function isVisable( element, container ){

  var elementTop = $(element).offset().top,
      elementHeight = $(element).height(),
      containerTop = $(container).offset().top,
      containerHeight = $(container).height();

  return ((((elementTop - containerTop) + elementHeight) > 0)
         && ((elementTop - containerTop) < containerHeight));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MPuDW/

Comment: I'll have to test that out, and go up the parent tree, checking if any element has scrollbars and, if so, perform this check everytime until I reach the body... I'll try that as soon as I can.

Comment: One thing to note, this only will work within the contained element. If the selected element is visible within the container, but the container isn't visible, it will still return true.

Comment: For a certain case, but not exactly. It does not take into account that the `element` could be within `container`, but if `element` is within a child of `container` that is also scrollable, and outside it's boundary, it will not be visible. In short, it does not cover all cases. I believe the ideal solution would have to do with going up the parents and validating that each parent has scrollbar, *then* check `element`'s offset within it. Since it would not be efficient, I decided to change my design. However, I'd still be interested to see a fully working solution to this...